# problem using GSM shield and GPS shield in one Arduino UNO R3

Tags: gsm, tinygps

i try to program use the GSM shield Arduino with Arduino UNO i did it successfully but after that i try to use GPS shield but when i add the #include  for the program i got the error

```
#include <GSM.h>
#include <TinyGPS.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h> // when i add that one i got the output eroor 
// PIN Number for the SIM
#define PINNUMBER ""
```

i got this error out put

```
Arduino: 1.6.6 (Mac OS X), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Uno"

libraries/SoftwareSerial/SoftwareSerial.cpp.o: In function `__vector_3':
/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/arduino/avr/libraries/SoftwareSerial/SoftwareSerial.cpp:227: multiple definition of `__vector_3'
libraries/GSM/GSM3SoftSerial.cpp.o:/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/libraries/GSM/src/GSM3SoftSerial.cpp:499: first defined here
libraries/SoftwareSerial/SoftwareSerial.cpp.o: In function `SoftwareSerial::read()':
/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/arduino/avr/libraries/SoftwareSerial/SoftwareSerial.cpp:392: multiple definition of `__vector_4'
libraries/GSM/GSM3SoftSerial.cpp.o:/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/libraries/GSM/src/GSM3SoftSerial.cpp:487: first defined here
libraries/SoftwareSerial/SoftwareSerial.cpp.o: In function `SoftwareSerial::read()':
/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/arduino/avr/libraries/SoftwareSerial/SoftwareSerial.cpp:392: multiple definition of `__vector_5'
libraries/GSM/GSM3SoftSerial.cpp.o:/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/libraries/GSM/src/GSM3SoftSerial.cpp:487: first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
exit status 1
Error compiling.

  This report would have more information with
  "Show verbose output during compilation"
  enabled in File > Preferences.
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears the GSM library has its own conflicting copy of SoftwareSerial, and not necessarily a matching version unless you're lucky.

Not sure how well this would work but you can try removing the library reference to SoftwareSerial, and fiddle about to use the GSM library's SoftwareSerial.

Comment: Indeed, if both peripherals are serially connected, the "only one instance" restriction of the software serial library may be a problem.  Alternate libraries could be considered, but most likely an ATmega-based Arduino is not the best platform.   A GSM module with integrated GSM could be another choice.

Comment: True that; my solution almost definitely won't result in 2 separate serial streams, which are likely needed.  This page may be of interest (alternate libraries) http://www.ernstc.dk/arduino/tinycom.html

Comment: thanks , i used SerialGSM.h instead the GSM library i can receive message but when i send the message not send it :(